# Static content deploy generate thousands of weird folder names

Tags: magento2, security, static-content

i've run setup:static-content:deploy -f and now i'm getting a lot of strange folders on my pub/static/frontend folder For example one folder has the name "G7oLVFdw'; waitfor delay '0:0:6' -- " This folders arent "theme/language" folders.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**please run as give below command:**

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend --theme Vendor/mytheme -f 
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:flush
```